# Getx toNamed route not working, ROUTE REPLACE called automatically, controller delete

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm just navigating to new page using named routes, as soon as toNamed trigged new screen flashed, then closed console shows 'onDelete called', REPLACE ROUTE with navigating one.

1. main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      initialRoute: AppRoutes.splash,
      getPages: Pages.getPages,
    );
  }
}
```

2. Pages

```
abstract class Pages {
  static List<GetPage> getPages = [
    GetPage(name: AppRoutes.splash, page: () => SplashPage(), binding: SplashBinding()),
    GetPage(name: AppRoutes.login, page: () => LoginPage(), binding: LoginBinding()),
    GetPage(name: AppRoutes.home, page: () => HomePage(), binding: HomeBinding(), transition: Transition.fadeIn),
    //issue in last one.
    GetPage(name: AppRoutes.newTask, page: () => NewTaskPage(), binding: TaskBindings(), transition: Transition.fadeIn),
  ];
}
```

NOTE:  Navigating to NewTaskPage(),

3. Binding

```
class TaskBindings extends Bindings{
  @override
  void dependencies() {
   Get.put<TaskController>(TaskController());
  }
}
```

4. task controller

```
class TaskController extends GetxController{

@override
  void onInit() {
    //todo: fetch Task info.
    super.onInit();
  }

}
```

5. Task Page

```
class NewTaskPage extends GetView<TaskController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("NEW TASK"),
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text("No Working"),),
    );
  }
}
```

6. Navigating function

```
void navigate2NewTask() {
    Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.newTask);
  }
```

7. calling above function

```
class HomePage extends GetView<HomeController> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _homeScfKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
//SEE HERE
          onPressed: () => controller.navigate2NewTask(),
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
        key: _homeScfKey,
        drawer: HomeDrawer(),
)
}
}
```

New task page flashed and then the console shows this:

```
[GETX] GOING TO ROUTE /new-task
[GETX] Instance "TaskController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "TaskController" has been initialized
flutter: Splash navigation
[GETX] REPLACE ROUTE /new-task
[GETX] NEW ROUTE /app-home
flutter: Splash navigation
[GETX] "TaskController" onDelete() called
[GETX] "TaskController" deleted from memory
```

Please help.

Comment: why not use Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.newTask) instead of controller.navigate2NewTask()??

Answer (score 0):

You should call Get.find on the very first screen on your app, so GetX will not delete it:

```
YourController yourController = Get.find<YourController>();
```

it worked for me ✅